# Optimize SQL query with multiple join condition

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql tables like bellow:

```
table_category
-----------------
id | name | type    
1  | A    | Cloth     
2  | B    | Fashion    
3  | C    | Electronics    
4  | D    | Electronics

table_product
------------------
id | cat_cloth | cat_fashion | cat_electronics    
1  | 1         | 2           | 3    
1  | NULL      | 2           | 4
```

Here `cat_cloth, cat_fashion, cat_electronics` is ID from `table_category`

***It is better to have another table for category type but I need a quick solution for now.***

**I want to get list of categories with total number of products.** I wrote following query:

```
SELECT table_category.*, table_product.id, COUNT(table_product.id) as count
FROM table_category
LEFT JOIN table_product` ON table_category.id = table_product.cat_cloth 
    OR table_category.id = table_product.cat_fashion 
    OR table_category.id = table_product.cat_electronis
GROUP BY table_product.id
ORDER BY table_product.id ASC
```

Question: The sql I wrote it works but I have more then 14K categories and 50K products and the sql works very slow. I added index for cat_* ids but no improvement. My question how can I optimize this query?

I found the query takes 3-4 minutes to process the volume of data I mentioned. I want to reduce the execution time.

Best Regards

Comment: Performance questions should include EXPLAIN ANALYZE and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. Slow is a relative term and we need a real value to compare. MySQL Also Please read [How-to-Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Mike Andrew - can you please post some sample data on sqlfiddle.com to test the queries ?

Comment: @e4c5 I am not sure how to benchmark but I found the query takes 3-4 minutes to process the amount of data I mentioned. I want to reduce the execution time

Comment: so post that in your question, along with the output of explain and preferable the show create tables.

Comment: I have voted to close this since you have made no effort to provide required information despite two requests from me and one from @BerndBuffen

Comment: Still need `EXPLAIN` result..if you confuse, just add `EXPLAIN` before your query.. and expected result is needed cause it feel like your query is *wrong* somehow..

Comment: You show two product IDs with the same ID, but different content with respect to one with cloth, another without.  Showing a few more sample actual data might help, but ALSO, show what you EXPECT the answer to be.  If grouping on product ID doesn't make sense with multiple records in the product table with the same product ID?  Maybe a type-o in sample presented here?  Are you trying instead to get how many products qualify into each individual category, such as a web search for a cloth, or electronic qualified item to display to users?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can say every "OR" either in "ON" or "WHERE" part is very cost expensive. It will sound very stupid but I would recommend you to make 3 separate small selects combined together with UNION ALL. 
This we do with similar problems both in mysql and postgresql and in some cases when we got "resources exceeded" we had to do it also for bigquery. So it is very stupid and you will have more work but it certainly works and it is much quicker in producing results then many "OR"s.

Comment: yes it is expensive and I am looking for a solution for this. But UNION ALL too expensive regarding my scenario. I tried UNION ALL too before posting and it takes tame multiple by 3 then current execution time. Thanks for your reply